# vscode regla de configuración para "files.exclude"

Tags: visual-studio, vscode

Estoy tratando de introducir una **regla en la configuración** en el fichero de configuración JSON de Visual Studio Code, por enésima vez... no sé, si lo que quiero es posible.

**Usando *"files.exclude"* trato de "excluir" todo el contenido de un directorio excepto
un directorio concreto del mismo que si quiero que aparezca.**

Por ejemplo, no quiero que el árbol de fichero y directorios del editor me muestre el contenido de "views/public/" excepto su carpeta "posts". He probado con:

```
"views/public/"      : true, 
"views/public/posts/": false,
```

Probé a ordenarlas de forma diferente, usar [comodínes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options), etc.
La regla *excluyente* prevalece siempre, si no la "rompo", es decir siempre se oculta todo o se muestra todo el contenido de "views/public/".

*Usando Visual Studio Code v.1.51.0 en Linux.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no hay (o no conozco) una forma directa, se puede usar esta forma, que duele a los ojos pero sirve:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "views/public/[^p]*": true,
    "views/public/?[^o]*": true,
    "views/public/??[^s]*": true,
    "views/public/???[^t]*": true,
    "views/public/????[^s]*": true,
    "views/public/posts?*": true
}
```

Comment: Muy buena @Pollo, si que duele un poco. Dejo la pregunta abierta a nuevas soluciones. Con la primera línea de tu solución casi me vale: "views/public/[^p]*": true,` solo muestra los directorios / ficheros que empiezan por "p" dentro de "views/public/"